# Preventing user to see video URL in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, video-streaming, html5-video

I have an web page where users can view videos.

But the problem is when I inspect the page, it shows the video url.

So is there any idea how we can hide video source like youtube and other videos portal ?

Comment: any user can get the url by right clicking on your page and choose inspect. Don't bother.

Comment: You could use something like Cloudflare's Stream, they issue blob urls which the user can't directly open, that's also how youtube does it in the end

Comment: If you went to the trouble of creating a man in the middle server and the cost of re-streaming the video yourself... I suppose it would be possible. But it would be an awful lot of work... and that would just obfuscate the original source of the video. They'd still know where the resource came from to their device. There's really no way around that part.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to hide the video URL entirely without resorting to browser plugins. You can obscure it though, but in most cases they won't be worth it.

Using [Media Source Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/) you can deliver segments of video data using obscured urls. And the URL won't be immediately visible in the source of the page. This is similar to what Youtube or Netflix does but requires massive engineering work on the backend. This is also the technique used to play MEPG-DASH with e.g. dash.js or shaka-player.

Set it using Javascript, so it's not viewable with view source, it won't help with inspecting though.

If your issue is people copying the stream URL and using it in their own players, then you might look at protecting it with some sort of tokens security. This is supported by almost any CDN out there, and there are plenty of open source systems to do it in most programming languages.

Lastly, if the issue is that you don't want anyone to copy the content, you can apply DRM protection. One of the easiest and straightforward ways to get started with that, might be using [Azure Media Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/content-protection/).